# loop through firebase database object and ng-repeat the result

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am ng-repeating the objects stored in my `$firebaseArray`object.

`mycontroller`:

```
var projectquery = DatabaseRef.ref("projects").orderByKey().equalTo("-KUTPrs6ARZXjbjtNr7O");
$scope.projectslist = $firebaseArray(projectquery);
```

html view with `ng-repeat`:

```
<tr ng-repeat="obj in projectslist">
    <td>{{ obj.field1}}</td>
    <td>{{ obj.field2 }}</td>
    <td>{{ obj.field3 }}</td>
    <td>{{ obj.field4 }}</td>
</tr>
```

this is displaying only one project because I am passing in the project key manually to equalTo and thus filtering to show one.

From the other hand, I am getting a set of project keys from the below function by doing a forEach on another database where I get my project keys:

```
var keyquery = DatabaseRef.ref('/users/' + userId).orderByKey().once("value")
    .then(function onSuccess(snapshot) {
        snapshot.child("savedprojects").forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var userprojects = childSnapshot.val();
            console.log("my list is :", userprojects );
        });
    });
```

the output of the console is like:

```
my list is : -KUTLAZENGlxtzCtEfaZ
my list is : -KUTLM8r_kmVSTaxzLW5
my list is : -KUTPrs6ARZXjbjtNr7O
```

### Question:

how is it possible to pass on the above list of project keys obtained from forEach into the first function which shows the projects and filters them by key?

Could somebody please give a relevant answer and help me solve this, without referring to other answers which are not directly related to my question?

thanks in advance!

### edit:

my DatabaseRef refers to this factory, which is initializing the firebase database:

```
app.factory("DatabaseRef", function() {
    return firebase.database();
});
```

### update:

After implementing [Gourav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5429428/gourav-garg), my console shows undefined in place of the project IDs:
[image]
as you can see, the user has six projects under his profile, but all of them are empty and undefined.

### update 2:

here is console output after Gourav's edit:
[image]

and the error for ng-repeat:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

I don't know much about DatabaseRef but this might help.

```
$scope.projectslist = [];
DatabaseRef.ref('/users/' + userId).orderByKey().once("value")
.then(function onSuccess(snapshot) {
    snapshot.child("savedprojects").forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
        var userprojects = childSnapshot.val();
        console.log("my list is :", userprojects);
        var projectquery = DatabaseRef.ref("projects").orderByKey().equalTo(userprojects);
        $scope.projectslist.push(($firebaseArray(projectquery))[0]);
    });
});
```

Comment: i am trying to get this work, but no sucess. anything missing?

Comment: Actually it is showing three empty lines, it is trying to display them, but the values are empty. The table is there with three lines separating the rows, but the values are missing.

Comment: try this. Actually, query return an array, either push first value or concat.
$scope.projectslist.push($firebaseArray(projectquery)[0]);

Comment: I tried this, but not working, maybe I didn't implement it correctly. Could you please update your answer in this regard taking into account the edit you suggested. thanks

Comment: actually, I had empty lines for each project in my ng-repeat view. But now after implementing your edit, there is no empty line anymore, and I posted the console output, which throws in undefined for each project.

Comment: can you try changing `$scope.projectslist.push(($firebaseArray(projectquery))[0]);` to `console.log($firebaseArray(projectquery));` and check console again what actually query is responding

Comment: I added the console screenshot after implementing your very last edit in your comment.

Comment: This seems same as I told you earlier. Sorry to bother you again can you please change `$scope.projectslist.push(($firebaseArray(projectquery))[0]);` to `$scope.projectslist.push(JSON.stringify($firebaseArray(projectquery))[0]));` 

and in your html 
`<tr ng-repeat="obj in projectslist">
    <td>{{ obj}}</td>
</tr>`

Comment: It is me bothering you! You are helping me! Thanks.
regarding the ng-repeat, I think I need to keep my own with reads each field separately into a table column for each object. <br /> however, with the stringify method, I get all of the info I need, but in raw text format, not in table format with keys and values. I am posting a screenshot of this in a minute.

Comment: here is the link for {{obj}} and what it displays when changing into stringify. http://pastebin.com/iw0JnjYN

Comment: sorry regarding the dumping. i had a bit of code left there from user profile, which was dumping the whole user object. nothing to do with the projects and stringify.

Comment: Replace
`var projectquery = DatabaseRef.ref("projects").orderByKey().equalTo(userprojects);
        $scope.projectslist.push(($firebaseArray(projectquery))[0]);`
with
var projectqueryData = $firebaseArray(DatabaseRef.ref("projects").orderByKey().equalTo(userprojects));
        $scope.projectslist.push(JSON.stringify(projectqueryData[0]));

Comment: it is not working, here is my screenshot of code, in case I am missing something: http://i.imgur.com/mtMIivm.png
and here is the console screenshot, http://i.imgur.com/rwtPXS9.png

Comment: Replace:
 `var projectquery = DatabaseRef.ref("projects").orderByKey().equalTo(userprojects);
        $scope.projectslist.push(($firebaseArray(projectquery))[0]);`

With:
`DatabaseRef.ref("projects").orderByKey().equalTo(userprojects).then(function onSuccess(project) {
$scope.projectslist.push(JSON.stringify(project));
});`

Comment: Only in this case I don't get console errors, and my table is showing, but the values are empty: `var projectquery = DatabaseRef.ref("projects").orderByKey().equalTo(userprojects);
                    $scope.projectslist.push($firebaseArray(projectquery));` here is the screenshot of the empty table: http://i.imgur.com/uByHT3c.png as you can see, i numbered the six projects which should normally be displayed, but the values are not shown.

Comment: in your last reply change `$scope.projectslist.push($firebaseArray(projectquery));` to 
`$scope.projectslist.push(JSON.stringify($firebaseArray(projectquery)));`


If I am not wrong, its a async call and we have to wait for the response.

Comment: regarding your edit one above, here is the code+error screenshot, so you can see the line number of the code as well. http://i.imgur.com/WCNYCcG.png

Comment: and here is when i did according to your very last comment http://i.imgur.com/oe9JyR9.png

Comment: sorry missed once, please add **.once("value")** before then
`DatabaseRef.ref("projects").orderByKey().equalTo(userproject‌​s).once("value")`

Comment: in which one exactly, because there were many edits, I am confused now. could you please post the entire part which I should replace? thanks

Comment: In my prev comment which caused exception, replace this to 
`DatabaseRef.ref("projects").orderByKey().equalTo(userproject‌​s).once("value").then(function onSuccess(project) { $scope.projectslist.push(JSON.stringify(project)); });`

Comment: you have to debug what exactly project containing. 
from the error it seems it contain circular ref

Comment: what should i do exactly to debug?

Comment: replace `$scope.projectslist.push(JSON.stringify(project)); ` with `debugger;
$scope.projectslist.push(JSON.stringify(project));`
open console and check project data

Comment: here is the screenshot http://i.imgur.com/3EdrkX8.png
in which, as I go forward, the userprojects value gets iterated over the six projects keys available for that user.

Comment: and here is the above code, uncommented, and then commented the below one. http://i.imgur.com/IJaMqUm.png

Comment: and here is the one I had, and is only showing empty lines http://i.imgur.com/TaDZLlk.png
the userproject ID gets passed into equalTo filter. But when the projectquery gets passed into the firebaseArray, you can see that the array is empty.

Comment: can you disable minification?

Comment: what are you using for bundle or minification?

Comment: i don't know, i don't think i am using anything to minify the code!

Comment: replace `$scope.projectslist.push(JSON.stringify(project));` with `$scope.projectslist.push(JSON.stringify(project.val()));`

Comment: hover on project.val()